# SQL JOIN Concept

Tags: sql, join

recently i was so confusing about SQL JOIN execution order. Supposed I have 3 tables like this:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyDK7.png)

and this is the query:

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM Table_a a 
 LEFT JOIN Table_b b ON a.id=b.id
 INNER JOIN table_c c ON b.id=c.id
```

What do you think the result will be? according to what I read in several webpages, the order will not affect the result.

This is what I thought the result will be A left Join B, then the result will be inner join with C. So depends on what the result of A left join B, will determine the result of final result. Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: The order doesn't matter (although a logical order reads easier). In your query, the final inner join turns the left join into an inner join. The join condition `b.id=c.id` can only be applied on not null values ('something' = null => null).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does SQL join work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439152/how-does-sql-join-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_a a LEFT JOIN
     Table_b b
     ON a.id = b.id INNER JOIN
     Table_c c
     ON b.id = c.id;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_a a INNER JOIN
     Table_b b
     ON a.id = b.id INNER JOIN
     table_c c
     ON b.id = c.id;
```

Huh?  How does this turn into an inner join?  Well, first now that the SQL is interpreted from left-to-right, so your query is interpreted as:

```
SELECT *    
FROM (Table_a a LEFT JOIN
      Table_b b
      ON a.id = b.id
     ) INNER JOIN
     table_c c ON b.id = c.id;
```

That is, the `b` in the last condition is the result of the `left join`.  If there is no match, then `b.id` is `null` and the condition is not true.  Hence, those rows are all filtered out.

I recommend the following rules when working with joins:

- Put all `INNER JOIN`s first.
- Use `LEFT JOIN`s for all subsequent joins.
- Don't use `RIGHT JOIN`s.

For me, this works for something like 99.9% of queries.  There are some cases where alternative methods are preferable -- I usually use subqueries for those.

Comment: HI Gordon, could you elaborate why the query left join is equivalent with inner join in this case?

Comment: I prefer to mix `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN` in single queries, while using table names like `[SELECT]` and `[FROM]`...

Comment: @Anthony.G . . . If you would like to know my indentation style, you can read the first chapter of **Data Analysis Using SQL and Excel**.